# Abstract class created in an unconventional way

Tags: java, android

Please, I need your help.

About this abstract class in Android Studio:

```
public abstract static class Adapter<VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
```

Are there any Java books that explain this?

I've never seen an abstract class being created this way.
Using these symbols: <>
And within these symbols, there are an extend method. I've never seen before.

Does anyone know some book that explains about this kind of abstract class?

Comment: google java generics

Comment: abstract static - what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

That `Adapter` class is an **abstract class** that you have to implement to use `RecyclerView`.

So you shouldn't leave it as abstract unless you are going to make a child class of it and implement again.

It basically means that

> It is an abstract class that uses VH as [generic type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html).

So you will write something like

```
public class MyAdapter extends Adapter<MyViewHolder> {
```

Then there are three methods you have to override.

1. `MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)`
2. `void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position)`
3. `int getItemCount()`

You can find android recyclerview implementation example [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#java).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for responding.

So it's only in Android programming that there is this kind of abstract class?

This kind of programming, which I have never seen before, I think it's quite complex.

I had already seen the Android's documentation, containing this information that you passed me. But I found it difficult to understand.